# TexShop engine with Knitr and latin1 encoding option

Tags: r, encoding, knitr, iso-8859-1

How can I edit the Knitr.engine in TeXShop for other input encoding?

Actual Knitr.engine:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin
if (Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('$1')") then
   latexmk -pdf "${1%.*}"
fi
```

With my "magical thinking" I try

```
...
if (Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('$1', encoding='latin1')") then
...
```

without success.

Edit: This script now works with R3.4 and TeXLive 2016.